# No authorization for data preview in ADT 2023-06

Tags: authorization, cds, abap-adt

The error I faced when trying to access view `demo_cds_curr_conv` on ABAP BTP Trial is

[image]

I want to find out what is the authorization missing, is there a way?

In classic ECC accessed via SAPGui we can use SU53 for that, it shows which exact auth object is missing for the last run tcode.
Is there something similar in ADT?

Answer (score 0):

I am reposting here [SAP answer](https://community.sap.com/t5/technology-q-a/no-authorization-for-data-preview-in-adt-2023-06/qaq-p/12750766/comment-id/4785879#M4785879) to this question:

this particular view is not C1-released for language version 5, so usage/data preview is not possible.

A little bit of context: The C1-contract is described here https://help.sap.com/docs/btp/sap-abap-development-user-guide/use-system-internally-c1

Whether a specific object is C1-release can indeed by found in ADT in Properties > API State:

[image: 1]

DEMO_CDS_CURR_CONV has no contract set and is therefore not released in BTP ABAP.